# How can I persuade my manager to include my name in the article if there's no attribution policy?

Tags: professionalism, manager, teamwork, intellectual-property

I work for a company as a copywriter. My core responsibility is to write engaging marketing content related to the product I'm advertising. Recently, I've written an article on my own initiative. I volunteered to relate the product to a hot trend.

It turned out to be the most successful article that received the highest traffic in the website's history. The company decided to publish it for the conference in a form of a brochure, and when I asked the manager to mention my name (write it somewhere at the end of the article in small letters + the name of our designer, because he did a great job), **my request was turned down**. The manager said it was team work and mentioned the names of business developers instead, who are not related to the article at all. Now it looks like a 4-page business card.

I feel a little bit offended. I wouldn't have any problems if it was assigned to me by management, as sometimes I act as a shadow writer. I think it would be fair to mention the author's name in this case.

How can I persuade the manager to add my name in the published version on the article? I could add it to my portfolio then.

Comment: Hello @Irene and welcome to The Workplace. I am afraid that "Should I" questions are mostly off topic here on the site, as they are asking us to make a choice for you. Can you please reword your question to be more answerabe? Perhaps about how can you manage to get your name in the paper, or something similar

Comment: When you say the article was written "on your own initiative", does that mean that your manager didn't tell you to do it, that you did it on your own personal time outside of work, or something else entirely?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I'm not asking to make a choice for me, but for advice on how to handle the situation professionally.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, the article on the website did not mention my name, but I hoped it could be mentioned in the brochure at least.

Comment: @NuclearWang I came up with the idea to write this article, the manager liked it, so I continued working. I'm always trying to show initiative as a writer and suggest new ideas.

Comment: @Irene the point is that your question is quite broad and lacks a goal that we can address. "How should I react" is really a choice you have to make, but you give us no alternatives or details on the possible reactions you can take. If you narrowed down your question and rephrased it I am sure you will get good answers and feedback

Comment: @GrayCygnus Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the question.

Comment: No problem @Irene we are all here to help each other. Without intentions of bothering or picking on you, I am afraid that the new question is also hard to answer. Any answer will be just speculation, as we would be guessing what are the reasons for your manager to do that... only him can really answer that one. Maybe you can try with questions like: "What strategies can I take to get my name recognized on the article, while being professional?", "How can I persuade my manager to include my name on the article?"...etc. Maybe something in those lines could be more answerable

Comment: @GrayCygnus Thank you for your help. I've used your suggestion and edited the question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, they are always attributed with the author's name.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ok, will try to explain. Previously, the company published every article I wrote under the name of "bla bla expert." Now, everyone has an account and publishes articles from their own account with first and last name. The article we're now discussing belongs to the authorship of "bla bla expert," but still, it was written by me and it was my initiative. So I thought that if they are now publishing articles with personal names, mine can also be included in the brochure.

Comment: How can I make someone else do something they have already told me no about is not on topic here. Go to [IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) they love wonderful questions like this

Comment: The title is misleaing. You already asked, he said no, and now you want to know how to persuade him? Maybe a more interesting or useful question would be (for future reference) a better approach on how to persuade him (assuming he hasn't already said no).

Answer (score 2):

> I feel a little bit offended. I wouldn't have any problems if it was
>   assigned to me by management, as sometimes I act as a shadow writer. I
>   think it would be fair to mention the author's name in this case.
>
> How should I react?

You should react by talking to your manager privately when you both have a few free minutes.

You should learn what the company's policy is regarding attribution and bylines.  Every company that publishes writing has such a policy - even if it isn't written. In your case, the policy may just be "the manager decides on a case by case basis".

You should come to an understanding as to when your name will be mentioned and when it will not. Make sure you understand the policy when an article is assigned, and when it is written of your own volition. Make sure you understand how attribution is carried forward (or not) onto derivative materials like brochures.

Then, if the company's practices don't meet your needs, you should find a new job at a company where their author attribution practices won't offend you.

Alternatively, work as a freelance writer and insist that all of your published materials include your name as author.

Comment: My company doesn't have any policy in terms of content attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel offended but take it as an opportunity to learn about your company's ethics and your manager's nature. Next time you should be more careful about such things.

No body can restrict you from claiming that you have written that article. One way to show around that you are the writer is to put comments like "Thank you guys for appreciating my work and being my inspiration, this encourages me to produce great articles like this." if page has any comments section. That way you can get attention without offending anyone. also you can make a tiny blog where same article is published under your name and provide links to sites (and magazines or news papers if any) where article is published. Same thing can done over email as thank you note.